# Pinpoint a Row by searching for a value in a column in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks

I am trying to work out how to pinpoint which row I need my script to point at.

I have a Jobsheets app in Glideapps that my engineers use to complete jobs in the field. This is based on data from google sheets.

Using Glideapps and google sheets, I have it set up to trigger a webhook when I press a button on my Glideapp.

This webhook is linked to a google Scripts webapp. When triggering the Webhook in Glide, it gives 2 values. jobNo (Job Number) and rowId (Row ID).

So in my script, I have the following (I'm new to scripts so not 100% this is correct):

```
function doPost(e){
const contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)
console.log("contents.params", contents.params)
const jobNo = contents.params.jobNo.value;
const rowId = contents.params.rowId.value;

}
```

So in theory, this should pull the Job number and Row ID from glide.

I now need to be able to search my job numbers column (Column C), find the cell that matches the jobNo from the request, and then get that whole row.

At the minute I am using getLastRow(); to run my action, but the job that my engineers complete wont always be the last row so I need to be able to run my action for a specific row.

//In Short:
What I have at the minute:

```
let lastJob = sheet.getLastRow();
//Action
```

What I need:

```
let Job = sheet.(Row that contains jobNo)
//Action
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you are going to do with `job` but this will find the row containing `jobNo`.

**Code.gs**

```
function doPost(e){
  const contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)
  console.log("contents.params", contents.params)
  const jobNo = contents.params.jobNo.value;
  const rowId = contents.params.rowId.value;
  let spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById("the id of the spreadsheet")
  let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("The Sheet Name");
  let values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  // it is assumed the jobNo will never match the header
  let job = values.find( row => row[2] === jobNo );
  // job will be the entire row matching the jobNo
  if( job < 0 ) throw "Job not found"
}
```

**Reference**

- [Array.find()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I have tried what you said, but its Failing to run unfortunately. Im not sure what its failing on as it doesnt give me any logs when its ran through the webapp.

Answer (score 0):

```
function doPost(e) {
  const contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  console.log("contents.params", contents.params);
  const jobNo = contents.params.jobNo.value;
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  let sh = ss.getSheetByName("The Sheet Name");
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 3, sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  let idx = vs.indexOf(jobNo);
  return sh.getDataRange().getValues()[idx];
}
```

Comment: So what will I then use to get the row? for example, in that row ive gotta get the value of column 42.

would I use:

sh.getRange(idx, 42).getValue();
?

Comment: The row is what is returned.   The row number is idx + 2

Comment: But if I return there, then I cant do the rest of my action inside the doPost?

Comment: Were all supposed to be programmers here.  If you don't know how to rewrite such a simple code then this forum is probably the wrong forum for you.

Comment: Who said anything about not knowing how to rewrite it? I explained in my question that im new to scripts so, your pointless, arrogant remark was unnecessary.

Anywho. I worked it out.